# improving the detection accuracy by using euclidean distance between its Centroids

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scipy, object-detection

I'm working on a project where i have to detect colored cars form video frames taken from Bird's eye
view.

[image] [image]

For detection i used Histogram backprojection to obtain a binary image that suppose to contain only the target region of interest.

The process works fine until i tried to generalize the detection by testing it on video that contains object with similar color distribution ( like me crawling under the table and parts of my T-shirts are visible)

[image][image: 1] [image: 2-a][image: 3]

As you can see, both car and irrelevant objects **are moving** and the detection results are:

[image: b1]

[image: b2]

As you see irrelevant objects that share similar color distribution are shown in the binary images. However, thanks to Stack overflow experts i could improve the detection by telling the algorithm to choose the blob that represents the target object by adding the following constraints:

1-Rectangularity check
2-area and ratio check

with above constraints i could get rid of large irrelevant objects that are detected. However, for small object (see binary images), it doesn't work that much **as the rectangularity for the target object (small red car) ranges between **(0.72 and 1)**** and the small irrelevant objects do fall in this range. So i decided to add another constraint which calculating the distance between centroids of the car moving every 5 successive frames and threshold depending on that distance by doing the flowing:

```
 import scipy.spatial.distance
 from collections import  deque

 #defining the Centroid
 centroids=deque(maxlen=40) #double ended queue containing the detected centroids
 .
 .
 .
 centroids.appendleft(center)
 #center comes from detection process. e.g centroids=[(120,130), (125,132),...
 Distance = scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(pts1_red[0], pts1_red[5])                        
 if D<=50:
    #choose that blob
```

So  tested that on different videos and turns out the the distance between the centroids **ranges between 0 and 50 (0 when the car stops).**

**So my question is:**

Is there a way i can invest this property so that it helps enhancing the detection in such a way so that the detection ignores the T-shirt?, Since when the car is no longer visible and the irrelevant object stays it will calculate the distance difference of the irrelevant object and this distance will get small till it is less than 50!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  Once the train is no longer visible, you want to calculate the distance between the orange shirt and _____ ?

Comment: @J'e. I mentioned that as an example. I mean when the train for example is no longer visible, the algorithm will consider the T-shirt as a candidate object and would calculate the distance between the irrelevant blobs of the T-shirt. What i want is that the algorithm ignores other objects by using the distance metric. Hope you understand my question. I've rephrased the question

Comment: @k.jbaili Just to clarify, you are suggesting that when the detection happens for each frame, you want to calculate the difference between centroids of the object in consecutive frames, and only choose that object whose centroid is in the range [0,50] of the object in the previous frame?

Comment: Also, is it possible for you to find out the location of the tracks somehow? That way you can pick the object which lies on the track and ignore the ones that are outside it.

Comment: @GaneshTata, Regarding your first comment, Yes exactly. You are right about the second comment. However, as you said if i searched for the colored car only in the track region i would habe solved the problem. BUT i want to a little bit generalize the Problem by not doing so and instead by choosing  only the contours that represent the car using the additional feature( which is the distance )

Comment: @GaneshTata And ofcourse if you have another idea, i would be thankful for:)

Comment: @k.jbaili We would be able to use the distance measure effectively if in the first frame, we can confidently select the desired object. From that point, for each subsequent frame the distance logic can be applied. Are you sure that you can select the coloured car blob in the first frame ( since there won't be any previous frame for distance comparisons)?

Comment: @GaneshTata. Just to make this clear. Since I'm working on a video frames, the cars would come in and then leave the FOV of the camera. I would say the algorithms detects the car the the very first frame. However, keep in mind that when the car leave and irrelevant objects are still in the FOV of the camera. What would the algorithm do in this case with the distance to avoid considering that object as a target object and select it!!!

Comment: @GaneshTata. Hope you could share your idea:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided by the OP, here is an approach to solve this problem.

**Sample Images**

I have create a few sample images that roughly represent the objects moving across time. The center object represents the car that we are seeking and the other objects have been detected incorrectly by the classifier.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The first four images represent a car ( centre object )moving from left to right, along with two other objects that have been detected incorrectly. In the fifth image, the car has moved out of the frame but two incorrect detections are still present. The sixth frame consists of a new car  entering into the frame with other incorrect detections.

**Solution - Code**

The comments contain information regarding the algorithm. We are computing the centroid of each blob and comparing it with the centroid of the previously detected/extracted blob.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
# Reading files and sorting them in the right order
all_files = os.listdir(".")
all_images = [file_name for file_name in all_files if file_name.endswith(".png")]
all_images.sort(key=lambda k: k.split(".")[0][-1])
print(all_images) # 

# Initially, no centroid information is available. 
previous_centroid_x = -1
previous_centroid_y = -1
 
DIST_THRESHOLD = 30
for i, image_name in enumerate(all_images):
    rgb_image = cv2.imread(image_name)
    height, width = rgb_image.shape[:2]
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(rgb_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 127, 255, 0)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  
    blankImage = np.zeros_like(rgb_image)
    for cnt in contours:
        # Refer to https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#moments
        M = cv2.moments(cnt)
        cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
        # Refer to https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/11/finding-extreme-points-in-contours-with-opencv/
        # https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_properties/py_contour_properties.html#contour-properties
        extLeft = tuple(cnt[cnt[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
        extRight = tuple(cnt[cnt[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
        extTop = tuple(cnt[cnt[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
        extBot = tuple(cnt[cnt[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
        color = (0, 0, 255)
        if i == 0: # First frame - Assuming that you can find the correct blob accurately in the first frame
            # Here, I am using a simple logic of checking if the blob is close to the centre of the image. 
            if abs(cY - (height / 2)) < DIST_THRESHOLD: # Check if the blob centre is close to the half the image's height
                previous_centroid_x = cX # Update variables for finding the next blob correctly
                previous_centroid_y = cY
                DIST_THRESHOLD = (extBot[1] - extTop[1]) / 2 # Update centre distance error with half the height of the blob
                color = (0, 255, 0) 
        else:
            if abs(cY - previous_centroid_y) < DIST_THRESHOLD: # Compare with previous centroid y and see if it lies within Distance threshold
                previous_centroid_x = cX
                previous_centroid_y = cY
                color = (0, 255, 0) 

        cv2.drawContours(blankImage, [cnt], 0, color, -1) 
        cv2.circle(blankImage, (cX, cY), 3, (255, 0, 0), -1)
        cv2.imwrite("result_" + image_name, blankImage)
```

Updating the threshold enables the algorithm to track the object's centroid across the frames. Since the object can move up and down a little, we want to match the centroids of objects found in the current frame, to the centroid of the car found in the previous frame.

**Solution - Results**

Green - Selected blob
Red - Rejected blob
Object centres have also been marked for reference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note** - This is not a perfect solution. It has several limitations, but it can help you to design an approximate solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful idea. However, however, i didn't understand what does updating the threshold do and why the first if statement is accessed only once because i increments according to the number of images( by me according to frames in the video)!?

Comment: @k.jbaili I have explained the significance of the if statement in the comment beside it ( It is for the first frame only, since you mentioned that you might be able to accurately find the car in the first frame of the sequence).
Updating the threshold enables the algorithm to track the object's centroid across the frames. Since the object can move up and down a little, we want to match the centroids of objects found in the current frame, to the centroid of the car found in the previous frame.

Comment: the follwing error was returned when i ran the code:      extLeft = tuple(cnt[cnt[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed

Comment: we're considering that the array three dimensional however numpy complaining it is 2-dimensional.

Comment: Could you pleae upload and send the link to the image for which you are getting the error?

Comment: These are the python3 library versions that I am using - 
opencv-python==4.4.0.44
numpy==1.13.3
I am not sure what is the problem here.